# How to control the sequence of rows in every column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe is five columns and looks like:

```
    Ca   O  Ca  Ca  Hy
0    1       1   1    
1                    2
2                    3
3                    4
4        5            
5    6       6   6    
6                    7
7                    8
8    9       9   9    
9                   10
10                  11
11      12            
12  13      13  13    
13                  14
14                  15
15  16      16  16    
16                  17
17                  18
18      19            
19  20      20  20    
20                  21
21                  22
22  23      23  23    
23                  24
24                  25
25      26            
26                  27
```

I wonder if one can control the sequences of the output columns!

The desired dataframe will look like:

```
     *Ca *O *Ca  Ca  Hy
0    1   2   3   4   5
1    1             
2    1    5            
3    1    6  7   8            
4    5                
5    6         
6    6                
7    6                
8    9              
9    9  12          
10   9  9   10   11
11  12              
12  13      
13  13              
14  13  13         
15  16  14  15  16  
16  16              
17  16              
18  19                
19  20      
20  20              
21  20                
22  23      23  23    
23  23              24
24  23    26       25
25  26                 
26   0    0          27
```

The most important that the *Ca column has the sequence: [Ca[0],Ca[1],Ca[22],O[0] ..........]
Is that possible?

> Edit: code source:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dx = pd.read_csv('new 1.txt', 'sample_file.csv', names =['A'])
dx = dx.A.str.split(expand=True)

dx.columns = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J']
dx.insert(7, 'Ca', np.where(dx['J']=='C', dx['B'], ''))
dx.insert(8, 'O', np.where(dx['J']=='O', dx['B'], ''))
dx.insert(9, 'Hy', np.where(dx['J']=='H', dx['B'],  ''))
dx3 = pd.concat([dx['Ca']] + [dx['O']] +[dx['Ca']] + [dx['Ca']] + [dx['Hy']], axis=1)
print(dx3)
```

> new 1.txt

It is a small version of PDB file, but the real data will be 2000+"
:

```
HETATM    1  CM  MEG A   1     -14.139   2.599   0.003                 C  
HETATM    2  HM1 MEG A   1     -14.184   3.047  -1.015                       H  
HETATM    3  HM2 MEG A   1     -15.130   2.652   0.503                       H  
HETATM    4  HM3 MEG A   1     -13.868   1.531  -0.121                       H  
HETATM    5  OM  MEG A   1     -13.151   3.216   0.791                       O  
HETATM    6  CA  MEG A   1     -13.442   4.591   0.930                       C  
HETATM    7  HA1 MEG A   1     -13.728   5.060  -0.039                       H  
HETATM    8  HA2 MEG A   1     -14.269   4.741   1.658                       H  
HETATM    9  CB  MEG A   1     -12.192   5.292   1.443                       C  
HETATM   10  HB1 MEG A   1     -12.354   6.389   1.558                       H  
HETATM   11  HB2 MEG A   1     -11.967   4.897   2.458                       H  
HETATM   12  OE  EG  A   2     -11.085   4.983   0.624                       O  
HETATM   13  CA  EG  A   2     -11.062   5.762  -0.553                       C  
HETATM   14  HA1 EG  A   2     -11.806   5.354  -1.270                       H  
HETATM   15  HA2 EG  A   2     -11.279   6.839  -0.368                       H  
HETATM   16  CB  EG  A   2      -9.677   5.652  -1.203                       C  
HETATM   17  HB1 EG  A   2      -9.407   4.585  -1.379                       H  
HETATM   18  HB2 EG  A   2      -9.744   6.130  -2.203                       H  
HETATM   19  OE  EGH A   3      -8.671   6.347  -0.482                       O  
HETATM   20  CA  EGH A   3      -8.359   5.709   0.742                       C  
HETATM   21  HA1 EGH A   3      -9.160   5.897   1.483                       H  
HETATM   22  HA2 EGH A   3      -8.193   4.614   0.615                       H  
HETATM   23  CB  EGH A   3      -7.114   6.338   1.352                       C  
HETATM   24  HB1 EGH A   3      -7.277   7.431   1.498                       H  
HETATM   25  HB2 EGH A   3      -6.939   5.881   2.349                       H  
HETATM   26  OH  EGH A   3      -5.991   6.108   0.548                       O  
HETATM   27  HO  EGH A   3      -6.097   6.674  -0.260                       H
```

---

Comment: can you provide your input as dictionary for clarity?

Comment: @mozway it has a txt file, and it is long! shall I post?

Comment: @Elsaid if it's in the range of size of what you showed this is fine I think. Else, craft a shorter dummy example.

Comment: @mozway please check my edit

Comment: I think I did something wrong: `df.fillna('', inplace=True)
df = df.astype(int)` I need to fill NAN with nothing `''` but I can not convert it to `int`